# Telerik rad treeview dotted line not visibile when to print

Tags: telerik

in telerik , radtreeview dotted line not  visibile when to print,

and how to change dooted line to single line

```
</ul>   
      <telerik:RadTreeView 
ID="RadTreeView3"
runat="server">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following CSS

```
.RadTreeView .rtLines .rtLI {
  background-image:url("Vertical.png") !important; 
  /*give a solid vertical line image*/
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

its crazy, but use following code ,it works:

```
.rtLines .rtFirst,
.rtLines .rtFirst .rtUL {
    border-right:solid thin white; 
}
```